# Find the XPath for "match text" from given xml code

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my xml code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><b><a class="s7intext" href="#">   match text</a></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><a class="s7intext" href="#">   match text 9000</a></b></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I am doing the online task.i tried this XPath expression

```
//tbody/tr/td/b/a[contains(text(), 'match text')]
```

But still it shows incorrect. Your answers will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you expect from your xpath? I have checked it and it seems doing returning both "a" elements, and this seems to be correct.

Comment: I have to select only the **match text** in particular

Comment: try `//tbody/tr/td/b/a[contains(text(), 'match text')]/text()`. (I'm just adding `/text()` at the end)

Comment: @derloopkat Thank you very much:) it works.